# Why is chlorpromazine not characterized as tricyclic?

Tags: organic-chemistry, molecular-structure, medicinal-chemistry

Chlorpromazine is an old ("typical") *anti-psychotic* medication with a chemical structure which I as a non chemist find almost identical to that of all *"ine" tricyclic anti depressants* such as imipramine, amitryptiline, nortryptiline, maprottyline, and alike.

If I understood correctly, imipramine itself and later its counterparts were all originally synthesized from chlorpromazine. That said, in any occasion I've read about chlorpromazine, never have I found it being described as a "tricyclic", but rather just as "antipsychotic" (instead "tricyclic antipsychotic" compared with "tricyclic antidepressant" as with its counterparts), so I ask: Why does chlorpromazine not characterized as tricyclic?

By the way, both chlorpromazine and tricyclic antidepressants tend to cause weight gain if it matters to the reader.

Comment: Apparently anti-psychotic phenothiazines and thioxanthenes got separate categories.  Why they did when there were still "tricyclics" with no more specific designation? Dunno and I don't see importance of that. BTW I think it's borderline off-topic when one asks 'bout some lame pharmaceutical categorisation and not for example biochemical aspects.